# Can I replace characters in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I'm working on an AppleScript to mount our Active Directory Home Shares and I've come up with the following part that looks at the logged in users "SMBHome:" and it gives me the users home share but the slashes are in the wrong direction "\" and need to change them to "/".

So far the AppleScript is:

```
set username to do shell script "whoami"

set homepath to do shell script "dscl '/Active Directory/CAMPUS/All Domains/' -read /Users/" & username & " |grep SMBHome:"
```

When run this gives me an output of

```
"SMBHome: \\\\server\\share\\username"
```

I'd love to have the next step replace the back slashes with forward slashes and remove:

```
"SMBHome: \\"
```

With a final outcome of:

```
//server/share/username
```

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to solving this problem. One is to use JavaScript for Automation (either by putting your AppleScript into an Automator workflow and then using a separate Run JavaScript action, or by re-writing the entire script in JXA), while the other is to use the `sed` and `cut` command line utilities via `do shell script`.

Here's the JavaScript approach:

```
var string = "SMBHome: \\\\server\\share\\username" // this would be your 'homepath' variable
var corrected = string.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace('SMBHome: ', '')
```

This script uses the built-in JavaScript `replace` function to match and replace text using Regular Expressions.

On the other hand, you could also use `sed` and `cut` in your AppleScript, like so:

```
set init to do shell script "echo ' " & homepath & "' | sed 's/\\\\/\\//g'"
set corrected to do shell script "echo " & init & " | cut -c 10-"
```

This uses `sed` for the RegEx, then `cut` to trim the first bit of the path from the string.

In both cases, the `corrected` variable contains the final, modified string. I should note that, while the desired behavior can be accomplished in pure AppleScript, it can be rather tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply @aaplmath, I actually just found the needed addition which is what you have and it does the job!

```
| grep SMBHome: | cut -c 10- | sed 's/\\\\/\\//g' "
```

Thank you for your input!